# Getting an error while using datename function with count fun in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(dw, created_at) AS day_name, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM
    users 
GROUP BY
    day_name
```

With this query, I am not able to get the count of the fetching dayname from from `created_at` column.

Please help me with this query.

Comment: You said in your title, you get an error - please show us **WHAT** that error is! Complete and precise

Comment: In SQL, the language, SELECT is applied *after* the GROUP BY clause but before ORDER BY. That's why you can't use aliases in `GROUP BY`. You'll have to use a subquery, a CTE or CROSS APPLY to generate the `day_name` value before using `GROUP BY`

Comment: BTW everyone gets confused by SQL. The language is simply quirky - it wasn't even built for relational databases. It was built as an independent IBM product for business users. It's designed by a committee of most database vendors and  DB academics so many of its quirks were introduced simply because that's what was convenient for this or that big vendor at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have changed it through CTE now its working.